# Using matplotlib stylesheets with the WXAgg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I really like the plots that come out from using the 'ggplot' stylesheet, which is straight forward using pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
#... plot some stuff ...
```

However, I'd like to now embed these pretty plots inside of a GUI, using the WXAgg backend.  For this, I use:

```
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

Is there any way to use this (or any stylesheet) through the backend?  Thanks!

Comment: Look at `matplotlib.style` which should have all the same functions with out having to import `pyplot`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that and got an error,  but I'll try it again when I'm at a computer and at least report back an error.    Thanks!

Comment: Yup, @tcaswell, I get: `'module' object has no object 'style'`.

Comment: Got it to work! was using version 1.3.1, updated to 1.4.3 and `matplotlib.style` is there now :)  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `style` was introduced in 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` module was introduced in v1.4 so you must be using a > 1.4.0.

The `style` module is imported into the `pyplot` namespace for convenience, but can also be directly imported from `matplotlib.style` with out importing `pyplot`.